# Someone just went through all my questions, downvoting them all

Tags: discussion

I just checked my reputation, and something like 33 minutes before this question on meta downvoted every single one of the questions I have asked on EL&U. Note that I've only asked 5 questions here.

It's clear that one person did it, possibly as retaliation for some slight?  Is this kind of activity considered abuse?  And if so, is this the way to complain about it, posing a question on Meta?

Comment: Give it 24 hours. There are "serial downvoting" detection mechanisms in the SE; there's a good chance the problem will fix itself within a day or so.

Comment: @J.R. I'd like to know who did it, so I can find out why, and if I have offended them, find some way to make them feel better.  No, really.

Comment: Or maybe they hated all my questions.  Hmmm.  Nobody liked any of my questions, anyway.  I think I'll go eat some worms.

Comment: That's unlikely to happen, unless the person opts to self-identify here, or leave a comment on one of the questions. (By the way, "that's unlikely to happen" refers to finding out who did it. As for eating worms, maybe that's unlikely, too, but who knows? Are there any bait shops near where you live?)

Comment: No, no bait shops nearby.  I have a garden, so I could maybe dig some up.  Maybe it was @JeffAtwood who did it.

Comment: No, don't post a question on Meta about it right now. Here's a post about the issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: You're somewhat too late with this advice, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @user814064, your comment answers the question, why don't you make it into an answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do against downvote troll?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2703/what-to-do-against-downvote-troll)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the serial downvoting mechanism worked and reversed the downvotes.  Nice!

Comment: Have another upvote for keeping us posted! Not that you can "spend" meta upvotes on main, but it's the thought that counts.